# Is there a neat way to do strdup() followed by strcat()?

Tags: c, c-strings

Say I wanted to duplicate a string then concatenate a value to it.

Using stl std::string, it's:

```
string s = "hello" ;
string s2 = s + " there" ; // effectively dup/cat
```

in C:

```
char* s = "hello" ;
char* s2 = strdup( s ) ; 
strcat( s2, " there" ) ; // s2 is too short for this operation
```

The only way I know to do this in C is:

```
char* s = "hello" ;
char* s2=(char*)malloc( strlen(s) + strlen( " there" ) + 1 ) ; // allocate enough space
strcpy( s2, s ) ;
strcat( s2, " there" ) ;
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this in C?

Comment: You could replace `strlen( " there" ) + 1` with `sizeof( "there" )`, that makes it a compile time expression. Other than that, I don't see how you could improve on your code.

Comment: @Prætorian: Most compilers nowadays optimize `strlen(<const>)` anyway (they usually understand `strlen` as a built-in function and apply special optimizations).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make one:

```
char* strcat_copy(const char *str1, const char *str2) {
    int str1_len, str2_len;
    char *new_str;

    /* null check */

    str1_len = strlen(str1);
    str2_len = strlen(str2);

    new_str = malloc(str1_len + str2_len + 1);

    /* null check */

    memcpy(new_str, str1, str1_len);
    memcpy(new_str + str1_len, str2, str2_len + 1);

    return new_str;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A GNU extension is [`asprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf) that allocates the required buffer:

```
char* s2;
if (-1 != asprintf(&s2, "%s%s", "hello", "there")
{
    free(s2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not really.  C simply doesn't have a good string management framework like C++ does.  Using `malloc()`, `strcpy()` and `strcat()` like you have shown is about as close as you can get to what you are asking for.

Comment: Sure, but that is building on top of what C natively offers.  You are still allocating a new buffer and copying both strings into it. C itself does not support what is being asked for.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a library like GLib and then [use its string type](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.31/glib-Strings.html#g-string-append):

> `GString * g_string_append (GString *string, const gchar *val);`
>
> Adds a string onto the end of a GString, expanding it if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by nightcracker, I also thought of

```
// writes s1 and s2 into a new string and returns it
char* catcpy( char* s1, char* s2 )
{
    char* res = (char*)malloc( strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1 ) ;

    // A:
    sprintf( res, "%s%s", s1, s2 ) ;
    return res ;

    // OR B:
    *res=0 ; // write the null terminator first
    strcat( res, s1 ) ;
    strcat( res, s2 ) ;
    return res ;
}
```